# Django Admin "Add" fails for non-default database

Tags: django, django-admin, multiple-databases

I have scoured the internet, and my problem feels like it may be a bug in the django admin tool, but it is probably not.

I am trying to add records to a non-default database using the django admin tool. I have setup my admin.py to use the MultiDBModel admin as described in the documentation.

```
class MultiDBModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # A handy constant for the name of the alternate database.
    using = 'brite_obs'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Tell Django to save objects to the 'other' database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the 'other' database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super().get_queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(ObsField, MultiDBModelAdmin)
```

The database works. It is connected I can view records i can change records, but when I try to add a record. I get the following error.

Exception Type: ProgrammingError

Exception Value:    (1146, "Table 'django_site.obs_field' doesn't exist")

django_site is the default database where as the database I am connecting to is brite_obs. I must have something connected incorrectly, but the fact that it works for viewing or changing records, but  not for adding records has me stumped.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception says that the table django_"site.obs_field" does not exist.

Check all fields u pass on submit (use debuger pdb/IPDB)

Read object from DB via shell console, view the attributes and check.

Try creating a new object in shell and view the attributes u get. see what is the diff.

when all this is done, u will know what is your mistake in admin page.

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same error, careful reading of the traceback revealed that the admin view was using the sqlite3 back end when it tries to create a new object.  The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) suggest that using a database router is the way to go so I copied and adapted the code provided, and it seems to work a treat - new objects created as expected.

My app is called "*dash*" and my second database (a mysql legacy db) is called '*external*'.

```
# dash/dbrouters.py

class DashRouter:
route_app_labels = {'dash'}

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return 'external'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return 'external'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if (
        obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
        obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
    ):
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return db == 'external'
    return None
```

Then add a setting in the project level *settings.py*:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['dash.dbrouters.DashRouter']
```

It's possible that the router overcomes the need for the custom admin class but I haven't tested that (why break something that works?).